# Python Django - Not able to download video completely in the client's machine using FileResponse

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm building a video downloader using Django. I have the `url` from where the video is played.

Inside the `download` view, first, I'm sending a request using `requests` library to that `url` with `stream=True` and storing the response in a `res` variable.

And finally, I'm returning the a `FileResponse` with the `res` and `'Content-Disposition' = 'attachment; filename="downloaded_video.mp4"'` and with content length.

```
def download(request):
    url = "https://rr-rkf.com/lkdlfj8eijkjjoifu99ooijLKJr8goijoijrg0j94"
    res = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    content_length = res.headers.get('Content-Length')
    content_type = 'video/mp4'
    file_response = FileResponse(res, content_type = content_type)
    file_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="download_video.mp4"'
    file_response['Content-Length'] = content_length
```

`url_patterns`

```
url_patterns = [
    path('/download', views.download, name='download')
]
```

When I go `\download`, the video started downloading and struck after downloading some bytes. In the browser it shows *resuming* for long time but there is no progress. But in the terminal, I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\DownloaderWebDjango\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 712, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\DownloaderWebDjango\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 833, in _raw_read       
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
urllib3.exceptions.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(212992 bytes read, 614518 more expected)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\DownloaderWebDjango\env\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 816, in generate
    yield from self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\DownloaderWebDjango\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 934, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\DownloaderWebDjango\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 877, in read
    data = self._raw_read(amt)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\DownloaderWebDjango\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 811, in _raw_read
    with self._error_catcher():
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\DownloaderWebDjango\env\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 729, in _error_catcher  
    raise ProtocolError(f"Connection broken: {e!r}", e) from e
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(212992 bytes read, 614518 more expected)', IncompleteRead(212992 bytes read, 614518 more expected))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\DownloaderWebDjango\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 173, in finish_response
    super().finish_response()
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 183, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\DownloaderWebDjango\env\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 818, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(212992 bytes read, 614518 more expected)', IncompleteRead(212992 bytes read, 614518 more expected))
```

The download speed is also **very slow**.

I tried to send response without `Content-Length`, the browser completes the download after downloading some bytes of the video but still I got the error and the video is not downloaded completely.

I'm using `python 3.11.3` and `Django==4.2`